# Calculation of Latitude and Longitude from given point and radius

Tags: java

I have latitude, longitude and a radius. Can you please help me in finding the another latitude and longitude from given points (latitude and longitude) and radius.

Comment: 2 questions: Do you want to find any one other point or how else; and (2) what have you tried?

Comment: if you're already given lat and long, what "other" lat and long do you have in mind?

Comment: **the* other latitude and longitude*...? *What* other latitude longitude?

Comment: I have to make a circle from given latitude longitude and radius .For this i need the points on circumference of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find out if another latitude and longitude is within a certain radius of your initial latitude and longitude?  If so, check out [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344165/calculate-gps-coordinates-to-form-a-radius-of-given-size).

Answer (score 1):

You will need more information than a point and a radius. You are also going to need the angle of the point in the circle.

Using the radius and the angle you have to apply [trigonometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) laws and draw and imaginary triangle with dimensions radius, height and width. The height and width will give you the distance from the current latitude and longitude.

For example:

```
for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++){
    double x = getDistanceX(radius, angle);
    double y = getDistanceY(radius, angle);
    if (angle > 180) 
        x *= -1;
    if (angle > 90 && angle < 270)
        y *= -1;
    double newLatitude = getCalculateLatitude(latitude, x);
    double newLongitude = getCalculateLatitude(longitude, y);
}
```